# Internet Explorer 11 became very slow after upgrading to Windows 10 plus some updates

Tags: performance, windows-10, internet-explorer, windows-update

Recently I updated my Windows 7 x64 to Windows 10 Pro x64. At that time I used Internet Explorer 11 and it worked fine.

But yesterday I open it again to access the same website of before (the Banco do Brasil bank website) and I discovered it became very, very slow - literally unsuportabble. That is strange since I don't remember installing any new software in the system that would justify giving problems to IE; the only differences from the first, successfulls usages and now would be some updates Windows 10 did automatically. Considering that the first date I used IE was at 17th of this month, the new updates that could have made IE so slow could be:

- Update of Windows 10 for systems basead on x64 (KB3081452)
- Update of Windows 10 for systems basead on x64 (KB3081449)
- Cumulative update of Windows 10 for systems based on x64 (KB3081444)
- Update of Windows 10 for systems basead on x64 (KB3081441)

I also notice that IE11 becames specially slow with this particular website, Banco do Brasil's homepage, while in general (Facebook for instance) it is running very faster although still with some lags when typing (not 100% normal).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you noticed problems with any other website? Did you try another browser? A tracert and pathping to your bank site ([edit] the results into your question) might give some clues.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the reply. As I sad, I tried with Facebook (and also with Google, although this one is always very quick) and I found out that the former wasn't "running 100%" - some lag was appearing while typing texts - although way better then with the bank's website (something like I type one letter and it takes 3-5 seconds for it to appear in the text editor). About another browser, no: it's a bank website which use some apps for security, so I neglected that option (although now I see the test is valid; I'll do it when back home)

Comment: install the Win10 WPT/SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk, open WPRUI.exe, select CPU, disk, network, VAlloc and under "scenario" select Internet Explorer and click on Start. Capture the slow IE ad after you captured 1-2 minutes, stop the trace. Share the ETL+NGENPDB folder (compressed as 7z) on OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 see if it works: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EFAF5B853A3A6D8!3625&authkey=!AF3xaP9YSIzf1Vs&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: some tools hook into IE (C:\Program Files (x86)\Trusteer\Rapport\bin\rooksdol.dll, C:\Program Files (x86)\GbPlugin\gbieh.dll). Look if removing the tools fixes the IE slowness.

Comment: @magicandre1981 well, that served for something! I deactivated Rapport service, but I couldn't do the same for the GBPlugin since it's the app used by the bank for security when logging into my account, and that was enough to make the website very much faster (enough this time to be able to use it). Nevertheless it's still considerably slow, still slower then the first time I used it when updated to Windows 10 (with lags when typing) and (something I didn't mention before) the On Screen Keyboard continues not to work.

Comment: @magicandre1981 and btw, this shouldn't be an acceptable solution since it doesn't actually attack the problem: the first time I use my bank's website on this PC after updating to Windows 10 I already had both apps installed and, as reported, I was able to use the website normally (including with the On Screen Keyboard). So these apps are very unlikely the source of the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what Microsoft changed in the updates, so that IE performs so badly. Report it to Microsoft (via support/feedback app in Win10)